# Прибавить к числам в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Добрый день, дорогие друзья.
Имеется строка "На пробеге до 45км расход топлива увеличивается на 2%, а при пробеге от 90км, пробег увеличивается на 2.5%"
Требуется вычленить все процентные характеристики, прибавить к ним 1 и вернуть обратно строку с новыми параметрами. Т.Е. должно получиться : "На пробеге до 45км расход топлива увеличивается на 3%, а при пробеге от 90км, пробег увеличивается на 3.5%"
Понимаю, что нужно пользоваться регулярками

```
/\d?\.?\d*%/g
```

Получаю массив всех значений, удаляю %, парсю как число, прибавляю 1, но как обратно засунуть эти значения в строку?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да. Может быть нецелое число.

Comment: Я понял, посмотрите, подходит ли https://jsfiddle.net/2hephorq/.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew не совсем. Таких параметров может быть больше 2-х.

Comment: Что значит "больше двух параметров"? 2% и 2.5% заменяются на 3% и 3.5% в моем примере.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да, но может быть пробег после 500км, 1000 км. Т.е. таких процентных параметров может быть больше чем 2.

Comment: Т.е. надо добавить 1 к 500км, 1000 км....? Тогда надо использовать `/(\d*\.?\d+)(\s*(?:%|[кмсг]м))/g` и добавить `$2` в callback.

Comment: Да, всё верно. Но я посмотрел, если передать строку с большим количеством параметров, то код всё равно работает, потому спасибо Вам, вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Comment: Чтобы закрыть вопрос, пожалуйста, отметьте ответ как верный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать `*` вместо первого `?`, чтобы находить числа полностью, добавить группу для захвата самого числа и использовать функцию обратного вызова в качестве аргумента замены:

```js
var rx = /(\d*\.?\d+)%/g;
var str = "На пробеге до 45км расход топлива увеличивается на 2%, а при пробеге от 90км, пробег увеличивается на 2.5%";
var res = str.replace(rx, function ($0, $1) {
  return (Number($1) + 1) + "%";
});
console.log(res);
```

В функции обратного вызова `$0` - это целое совпадение, `$1` - значение первой захватывающей группы и т.д.

Чтобы увеличить все остальные числовые значения, можно расширить шаблон и дополнить код следующим образом:

```js
var rx = /(\d*\.?\d+)(\s*(?:[кмсг]м|%))/g;
var str = "На пробеге до 45км расход топлива увеличивается на 2%, а при пробеге от 90км, пробег увеличивается на 2.5%";
var res = str.replace(rx, function ($0, $1, $2) {
  return (Number($1) + 1) + $2;
});
console.log(res);
```